# centered finite difference approximation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

> Show that the centered finite difference approximation for the first derivative of a function on a uniform mesh yields the exact derivative for any quadratic polynomial $P_2(x) = a+bx+cx^2$

Using the taylor series:

\begin{align}
f(x+h) &= f(x) +f'(x)h + f''(x) \frac{h^2}{2}+f'''(x)\frac{h^3}{6}+ \dots \\
f(x-h) &= f(x) -f'(x)h + f''(x) \frac{h^2}{2}-f'''(x)\frac{h^3}{6}+ \dots
\end{align}

From the first equation, we get the forward difference approximation:
$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+O(h).$$

From the second equation, we get the backward difference approximation
$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}+O(h),$$

and if we subtract the second equation from the first equation we get
$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}+O(h^2),$$

which is the central difference formula.

**But how do I use this to solve my problem?  Is this formula the same as the centered finite difference approximation mentioned in the question?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've well applied Taylor's expansion.

\begin{align}
f(x+h) &= f(x) +f'(x)h + f''(x) \frac{h^2}{2}+f'''(x)\frac{h^3}{6}+ o(h^3) \tag1 \label1 \\
f(x-h) &= f(x) -f'(x)h + f''(x) \frac{h^2}{2}-f'''(x)\frac{h^3}{6}+ o(h^3) \tag2 \label2
\end{align}

$$\frac{\eqref{1} - \eqref{2}}{2} : \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2} = f'(x)h + f'''(x)\frac{h^3}{6} + o(h^3) \tag{3}\label{3}$$

When the above equality is applied to a quadratic polynomial, we have $f^{(n)} \equiv 0$ for $n \ge 3$, so only the first derivative remains.  This should give you the desired result

$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}. \tag{4}\label{4}$$

---

(Edit in response to OP's request)

Apply given formula
$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}+O(h^2) \tag5\label5$$
to $P_2(x)$.

$$\begin{aligned}
P_2'(x) &= \frac{P_2(x+h)-P_2(x-h)}{2h}+O(h^2) \\
&= \frac{(a-a)+b[(x+h)-(x-h)] + c[(x+h)^2-(x-h)^2]}{2h}+O(h^2) \\
&= \frac{b(2h) + c[(x+h)+(x-h)][(x+h)-(x-h)]}{2h}+O(h^2) \\
&= \frac{2bh + c(2x)(2h)}{2h}+O(h^2) \\
&= b+2cx + O(h^2)
\end{aligned} \tag6\label6$$

Since \eqref{5} actually comes from dividing \eqref{3} by $2h$, and the *third and higher derivatives in \eqref{3} vanishes when $f = P_2$*, therefore, we can discard $O(h^2)$ in \eqref{6} and conclude that the *central finite difference approximation for the first derivative is exact when $f = P_2$*.

---

- When $O(h)$ is used to describe a *particular* function, it's used as an *object*.  In symbols: $f = O(h)$.
- When $O(h)$ is used as a *subject*, it describes a class of functions bounded by $Mh$ for a certain constant $M>0$.

When $P_{2}'(x) = b+2cx +O(h^2)$,
$$P_{2}'(x) - (b+2cx) = (b+2cx +O(h^2)) - (b+2cx) = O(h^{2}).$$
We won't say $O(h^2) = 0$ in *general*.  Instead, we need to make use of the *given* conditions to conclude further.

Comment: is this a complete solution? thanks for your post btw! I had an extra x on the ax in my question

Comment: @fr14 I've just read the statement to be proved above.  Daniel Moraes has completed his solution quicker than I do, so there's no point to duplicate the effort.

Comment: okay and his looks right in your opinion?

Comment: @fr14 I agree with his solution except the last equality $$O(h^2) = 0.$$

Comment: could you complete your solution?

Comment: @fr14 What I don't agree is just the way that the quantities are presented.  A simple rearrangement $$P_{2}'(x) - (b+2cx+O(h^2)) = b+2cx - b-2cx+O(h^2) = O(h^2)$$ and a simple explanation about where $O(h^2)$ comes from should do.

Comment: could you complete your solution? I can accept yours then

Comment: the first equalty is equal to 0 from the formula

Comment: @fr14 I've completed my answer in response to your request.  Sorry for late reply.  I was reading a blog article about setting up [static comments](https://staticman.net) on [personal blog](https://www.datascienceblog.net/post/other/staticman_comments/), which can be used as posting math.

Comment: @DanielMoraes You mean equation $(1)$ should be changed?  By saying "equal to zero", you mean that I should apply $f = P_2$ at that stage to conclude?  That greatly condenses my solution, but that hinders us to know more about $O(h^2)$ in the general settings.  While some rep farmers prefer the former to get their answer upvoted ASAP, mathematicians prefer a more general setting.  It's even better if the later is motivated by an observation.

Comment: I mean OP's formula, im not stating that $O(h^2)$ im showing it

Comment: what does the three dots mean in your explanation?

Comment: @DanielMoraes So you mean (1) by saying "first equality"?  You're showing that the difference quotient in OP's central difference formula is $O(h)^2$?  That's a good exercise.

Comment: @fr14 I assume that your mathematical maturity allows you to fill in the gap between formula and the results, so I used ... to omit them.  You may refer to the other answer to check your calculations if necessary.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 he already had it shown, although he made mistakes in the first two equations, i missed a $=0$ in my coment above

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I will accept your answer, could you fill in the missing …?

Comment: @DanielMoraes What mistakes?

Comment: @fr14 Done for you!

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 $$f'(x) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+O(h).$$ should be $$f'(x) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+O(h^2).$$

Comment: that makes sense now, thanks for everything!

Comment: @DanielMoraes Your claim is incorrect.  To see why, take $f(x) = x^2$.

Answer (score 3):

This is the centered finite difference approximation method,
basically you need to apply it to the general polynomial:
$f′(x)=\dfrac{f(x+h)−f(x−h)}{2h}+O(h^2)$    is what you already got

$P_{2}'(x)=\dfrac{(a+b(x+h)+c(x+h)^2) -(a+b(x-h)+c(x-h)^2)}{2h} +O(h^2)$

$P_{2}'(x)=\dfrac{a(1-1)+b(x+h-x+h)+c(x^2+2hx+h^2-x^2+2xh-h^2)}{2h} +O(h^2)$

$P_{2}'(x)=\dfrac{b(2xh)+c(4xh)}{2h} +O(h^2)$

$P_{2}'(x)=b+2cx +O(h^2)$
         Hence :
$P_{2}'(x) - (b+2cx) = b+2cx - b-2cx = 0 = O(h^{2})$, here we stating that the error goes to 0, it is also possible to see that $P_{2}''(x+h)-P_{2}''(x+h)=0$ and the higher order derivatives are $0$, so this statement is equivalent

Comment: sorry yes I edited the question, could you show me how this is done?

Comment: ok, will open a lit bit more

Comment: if you could include all the details I can accept it! sorry for the typo

Comment: i rewrited it, if you don't get a step i can exaplin it further

Comment: and this shows that the centered finite difference approximation for the first derivative of a function on a uniform mesh yields the exact derivative for any quadratic polynomial $P_2(x) = a+bx+cx^2$?

Comment: Yes, since from taylor expansion $O(h^2)$ represents the error, usually this is something hard to estimate, but polynomials are very well behaved

Comment: great, and no more details need to be added? I will try and understand it now

Comment: I guess no, depends on your actual knowledge

Comment: below GNUSupporter agrees with your solution besides the last equality $O(h^2)=0$

Comment: We can't say that $O(h^2) = 0$.  A sentence explaining that "the third or higher derivatives of $P_2$ is zero, so ..." should be added to justify the action of dropping $O(h^2)$.

Comment: I'm just using the formula he got to show that the error is 0, this sentence would explain the meaning of it, in the last sentence im derivating the polynom and comparing it to the centered difference

Comment: could you add this detail in?

Comment: i see no need, but i added it

Comment: thanks for your help, that makes sense now!

Comment: have you seen GNUs latest comment?